# How to split a string at every four words in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using C# 4.0 and have come across a situation where I have to split a whole string by every four words and store it in a List object.
So suppose my string contains: `"USD 1.23 1.12 1.42 EUR 0.2 0.3 0.42 JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53"`, the result should be:

```
USD 1.23 1.12 1.42
EUR 0.2 0.3 0.42
JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53
```

It shall be saved into a List object. I have tried the following

```
List<string> test = new List<string>(data.Split(' ')); //(not working as it splits on every word)
```

Comment: Do you havevno control over the creation of this string?  Seems like you could take your array of strings and just loop over them building a new string with every 4?

Comment: Actually the original string is read from a pdf file and  I have no control over that. Which is why I have top find to loop every 4 words.

Comment: So your string could be missing someone of the numeric values? Like `"USD 1.23 1.12 1.42 EUR 0.2 0.3 JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53"` (EUR with only two values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course my answer is not as glamour as the linq ones, but I wish to post this `old school` method.

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    string inp = "USD 1.23 1.12 1.42 EUR 0.2 0.3 0.42 JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53";
    while(true)
    {
        int pos = IndexOfN(inp, " ", 4);
        if(pos != -1)
        {
            string part = inp.Substring(0, pos);
            inp = inp.Substring(pos + 1);
            result.Add(part);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(inp);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int IndexOfN(string input, string sep, int count)
{
    int pos = input.IndexOf(sep);
    count--;
    while(pos > -1 && count > 0)
    {
        pos = input.IndexOf(sep, pos+1);
        count--;
    }
    return pos ;
}
```

EDIT: 
If there is no control on the numbers on the input string (for example, if some money has only 1 or 2 values) then there is no way to substring correctly in blocks of 4 the input string. 
We can resort to Regex

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

string rExp = @"[A-Z]{1,3}(\d|\s|\.)+";
// --- EUR with only two numeric values---
string inp = "USD 1.23 1.12 1.42 EUR 0.2 0.42 JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53";
Regex r = new Regex(rExp);
var m = r.Matches(inp);
foreach(Match h in m)
   result.Add(h.ToString());
```

this pattern accepts also numbers with comma as decimal separator and money symbols without any numbers ("GPB USD 1,23 1,12 1.42 "

```
string rExp = @"[A-Z]{1,3}(,|\d|\s|\.)*";
```

[RegEx Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: Ok..one more thing. Can the regex be modified to accept numbers in with commas? e.g. USD 1,625.87

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer answer updated, sorry for the delay, but nightime here.

Comment: Thanks for the updated Regex. I need to do more research on Regex as it's my weak point :(..

Answer (score 10):

With a little Linq magic:

```
var wordGroups = text.Split(' ')
                     .Select((word, i) => new { Word = word, Pos = i })
                     .GroupBy(w => w.Pos / 4)
                     .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Select(x=> x.Word)))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I think this would be a bit more robust with a Regex split just in case there is inconsistent white space usage.

Comment: I have tried this but it seems to split every 5 words rather than 4 words. Can you please check?

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer: Works fine for me - think about integer division and the grouping becomes obvious: 0,1,2,3 will be in the first group 4,5,6,7 in the next and so on.

Comment: Hmm..but still it's give me wrong output. It groups into 5 words. Is it because there are numbers in these words which might be causing problems?

Comment: Only inconsistent spacing would cause an issue as @ChaosPandion pointed out. The example you have given works just fine.

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is some inconsistent spacing in the original string. This has created more problems now :(. However your solution is correct, so I will mark it as answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to first split it at every word into a list, then write a little loop that re-combines each group of four words.

Comment: Could also do a Regex split on 4 words, but I'd probably do it your way instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reactive framework guys have an bunch of extensions for `IEnumerable<T>`. One of them is `Buffer` which does what you want so simply.

Here it is:

```
var text = "USD 1.23 1.12 1.42 EUR 0.2 0.3 0.42 JPY 1.2 1.42 1.53";
var result = text.Split(' ').Buffer(4);
```

And that gives:

[image: result]

Comment: Do I have to import another assembly because it does not recognize Buffer function?

Comment: You need to obtain the "Microsoft Interactive Extensions SDK" v1.1.10621. You can use NuGet to find "Ix_Experimental-Main". It comes with a bunch of very useful extensions - 'Buffer ', 'Case', 'Catch', 'Concat', 'Create', 'Defer', 'Distinct', 'DistinctUntilChanged', 'Do', 'DoWhile', 'Expand', 'Finally', 'For', 'ForEach', 'Generate', 'Hide', 'If', 'IgnoreElements', 'IsEmpty', 'Max', 'MaxBy', 'Memoize', 'Min', 'MinBy', 'OnErrorResumeNext', 'Publish', 'Repeat', 'Retry', 'Return', 'Scan', 'SelectMany', 'Share', 'SkipLast', 'StartWith', 'TakeLast', 'Throw', 'Using', 'While'.